# is it possible to list the latex support fonts in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: fonts

I want to check the font installed success or not, Now I using this command:

```
ubuntu@VM-0-16-ubuntu:~/Noto_Serif_SC$ updmap-sys --listmaps |grep fonts
Map csfonts.map enabled /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
Map kpfonts.map enabled /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
MixedMap    lxfonts.map enabled /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
Map nanumfonts.map  enabled /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
Map pxfonts.map enabled /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
Map sansmathfonts.map   enabled /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
Map txfonts.map enabled /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

but I did not know the latex recognize the fonts or not, for example, how to know the latex recognize font `IBM Plex Mono`? is it possible to show the fonts result in terminal command? for example, I can use the command like this:

```
xelatex-avaliable-fonts list|grep 'IBM Plex Mono'
```

to see the font was successfully used by xelatex.

Comment: Sorry, but it is highly unclear to me what you want to achieve. Using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you can use any font that you can install on your machine and use with other applications such as MS Word (including IBM Plex Mono). So, to my understanding, there is no point is asking whether or not a certain font is supported by LaTeX. If you use PDFLaTeX, you are bound to fonts that are available to use, since they need to come in a specific format. You can look up such font packages on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts) for example. Could you maybe clarify what problems you face exactly?

Comment: it was literally only minutes ago on your last question I said you needed to clarify which tex engine you are using, and you again ask a question with no information. lualatex and xelatex can use any `.otf` font you have on your machine

Comment: I think what you mean is that sometimes, `fontspec` fails to find a font using its font name and you would have to use the file name. Is this what you mean? Maybe have a look at the [`fontspec` manual (Part II, Chapter 2 "Font selection")](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) which explains the basics of this.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I meaning, I have already copied the fonts into the system path, but the compiler still told me could not found the fonts, I am so frustrated。

Comment: just saying "the compiler" doesn't help, lualatex, xelatex and pdflatex use completely different mechanisms to find fonts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
voss>FU-Python:$ luafindfont -n "*"
  No.                                            Filename                                                                                   Path
   1.                                Aboensis-Regular.otf                     /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/aboensis/
   2.                                     academicons.ttf                  /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/academicons/
   3.                      Academy Engraved LET Fonts.ttf                                                    /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/
   4.                                 ACaslonPro-Bold.otf                                                      /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Caslon/
```

Comment: See option `-x,` or `--xetex`