# What fonts are available in XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, typefaces

I am using `XeLaTeX`. I am aware of [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/). Is there anything similar for Xe(La)TeX?

Also, is there a way to tell whether a font (say, one listed in the *LaTeX* Font Catalogue) will work in XeLaTeX without just trying it?

Comment: xelatex is best not with the font catalogue but with opentype fonts, see the output of fc-list

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/689083/1090

Comment: Another way is LyX that show you a drop down menu with all available fonts on your OS when using XeTeX (note: XeLaTeX is really the same program). Even if yo prefer edit plain LaTeX could be useful, for instance, to show the the syntax to use it in the document.

Comment: As @DavidCarlisle hinted at: one of the main advantages of using either Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX is not being restricted to one of the "official" TeX-fonts: you can literally use any of the thousands of available opentype fonts.

Comment: The font catalogue lists also fonts on ctan that are meant for xelatex, look for "otf" or "ttf" in the descriptions.

Answer (score 4):

```
luafindfont -x "*"
```

lists all available fonts in the TeX and system dirs and does a check for XeTeX.

```
voss >luafindfont -x "*"
  No.                        Filename         Symbolic name                                                                        Path   X
   1.            Aboensis-Regular.otf              aboensis          /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/aboensis/   1
   2.                 academicons.ttf           academicons       /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/academicons/   1
   3.  Academy Engraved LET Fonts.ttf    academyengravedlet                                         /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/   0
   4.             ACaslonPro-Bold.otf        adobecaslonpro                                           /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Caslon/   0
   5.       ACaslonPro-BoldItalic.otf        adobecaslonpro   
 [...]
```

The last column has a 0 or 1.

- 1: it will definitely be found by XeTeX
- 0: it will only be available
  for XeTeX if it is in a system font directory